# Removing field from sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE signUp (
  userName CHAR(45)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  firstName CHAR(45)  NOT NULL  ,
  lastName CHAR(45)  NOT NULL  ,
  email VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL  ,
  pass VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL    ,
PRIMARY KEY(userName));
```

If i remove the AUTO_INCREMENT the error goes while importing to phpmyadmin. Will it cause any further problem?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you intend:

```
CREATE TABLE signUp (
  signUpId INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  userName VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL,
  firstName VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL,
  lastName VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL,
  pass VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (userName)
);
```

Notes:

- `AUTO_INCREMENT` is applied to integers, not strings.
- A good practice is to have an  auto-increment id for foreign key relationships (and other reasons).
- There is no rational reason to use `CHAR()` for names.  Padding with spaces is generally not useful.
- `UNIQUE` can be used to specify that the name is unique.
- The password should, of course, be encrypted.

Comment: @topicstarter "The password should, of course, be encrypted." with a slow hashing algorithm like Blowfish not with MD5, SHA1, SHA256 or SHA512 because those are fast hashing algorithms. Besides Blowfish isn't prone for rainbow tables attacks which MD5, SHA1, SHA256 or SHA512 are. Besides MD5, SHA1, SHA256 or SHA512 GPU bruteforcing is possible, Blowfish won't run that fast on GPU's